# Refreshing facebook like button after swapping url with javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, fbml

I have a problem where im using javascript to change the href of the facebook like button to change the url to a new link based on new ajax video content the user can load on the webpage. I want to make it so they can like each video based on the current one they are watching. The href is swapping out beautifully and i declared a FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("fbyoutubelike")); to refresh the like button. However nothing happens and I'm not sure what to do anymore. Does anyone have a clue as to how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB.XFBML.parse probably won’t re-render the tag if it sees the iframe is already there …

Instead of just manipulating the href attribute content, *remove* the existing like button tag (`<fb:like>` or `<div class="fb-like">`) from the DOM, *insert* a new one – and *then* call FB.XFBML.parse.

Comment: `<script>
 function urlSwapper(url){
  //document.getElementById("fbyoutubelike").setAttribute("href", [url]);
  $("#youtubelike").replaceWith('<fb:like id="fbyoutubelike" class="fb-like" href="'+[url]+'" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>').delay(1500, function() {
  FB.XFBML.parse;
});;
 };
    </script>`

Comment: Are you using two different element ids in that code on purpose, or …?

Comment: yes  youtubelike is the container div which houses the like button which has an id of fbyoutubelike

Comment: OK, just seeing this now – maybe you should actually _call_ FB.XFBML.parse if you want it to (re-)parse the document :-)

Comment: You did not call it at all. C’mon, _how_ are functions/methods _called_ in JavaScript again? _Not_ by just stating their name …